# Allow crawler access to protected pages

Tags: php, authentication, web-crawler

I have this piece of code in *PHP*

```
$uri = explode('/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$page = $uri[count($uri) - 2];

if(!(in_array($page, array("/*list of allowed pages*/")) || isset($_COOKIE['id'])))
{
    header("Location: " . HTTP . "?forbidden" ); //HTTP is the main directory of my website
    exit();
}
```

which prevents people from accessing pages such as *profile page* or *settings* if they are not logged in.

If they type in a link to one of those pages, they are redirected to the main page.

The problem is that when Googlebot tries to index any of these pages, he gets redirected too.

Is there a way (maybe using *robot.txt*) to allow Googlebot to access those pages, for instance from a dedicated account, or by disabling that redirection when I know there's a crawler instead of an user?

Comment: It seems unusual to want Google to crawl pages that aren't publicly accessible.

Comment: You could look at the user agent but that easily can be spoofed. You could look at the client IP as well, that's a bit easier BUT be aware that Google says that your pages should not vary based on it being their bot or not. There was a statement from a while ago that they down ranked pages that did that.

Comment: @Dave I've seen some important websites indexing pages such as the profile page so I thought it could be useful... Do you suggest to *remove it from my sitemap/place a no-robots meta tag*?

Comment: @user3783243 so should I remove them from Search Console?

Comment: From the code side you could do this, it just might hurt your SEO. You should research the SEO side before making the change. I haven't looked at SEO in a while.

Comment: @user3783243 what do you mean by researching the SEO side?